# html,js files show as text on mac, even after checking extension and text type

Tags: javascript, html, git, github, jekyll

I am working on a small college project for which I cloned https://github.com/gdg-x/zeppelin
However the html files show as the code itself. This is the case with a lot of files downloaded from the internet and from other computers.
I tried copying the code into textEdit, changed the format to plain text, made sure the extension was .html, I also tried saving it with sublime text but it still didn't work.
Can someone please help.

Comment: The files in that repository with `.html` extensions are not HTML documents.  [Read the instructions the repo provides you with](https://github.com/gdg-x/zeppelin/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

you need a server running to serve those files, you should at least read the readme in the git repo before asking in stackoverflow, and you should have at least some basic notion of what you are asking.

https://github.com/gdg-x/zeppelin

Read the readme Throutfully and you will be able to make it work

Comment: Thanks. I had the server running. Sorry for not mentioning that crucial piece of information. The problem was using text edit. I saved my .html files with Brackets and atom later and it all worked correctly.

Comment: you should have added that you eddited the files aswell, well glad you found the problem!